# Joining React flux with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactjs-flux

Is it good solution to join (interact) Redux with flux in one project like below? 
The state (inputText) is in our component (TOdoInput), not in store as it should be in Redux. Is it correct to have local state in Redux?

```
class TodoInput extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      inputText: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      inputText: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.addTodo(this.state.inputText)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type in your todo"
            value={this.state.inputText}
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Flux refers to a specific data pattern that lives outside of React involving stores and action creators. http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/ You're just using component state, which you can just call state :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct.

Local (component state) vs Global state (reducer) is a matter of concern.

For example take a tabs bar component which displays user informations

- A tabs bar should know which tabs is active. No other component cares about so it could be a local component state handled with `this.state`.
- On the other hand the user information of the tab is a global concern. Indeed, a lot of your components app should be interested to display name, age, etc. So this state should be stored in a reducer.

The main role of your TodoInput is to prepare the text to be send to the reducer. So input value is only important during the time the user is typing.

- you can format the text
- you can ask to a service is there is a typo
- ...

Once you are sure the text is OK with the concern of you app, you validate it. At this step, the concern of you value changes. It is now a value which could be consumed by other components. So it must be stored in a global store (the redux reducer).

Comment: but in this case (take the input value) it's a good solution, yes?